# Reference request: 2nd order Taylor expansion for functions between finite dimensional normed vector spaces using Fréchet derivatives

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a reference of 2nd order Taylor expansion for functions between finite dimensional normed vector spaces using Fréchet derivatives.

If this can't be found I think it would suffice for functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^d$.